# Adding vnet integration for the multiple Azure webapp slots using powershell or azure cli

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I'm trying to Vnet integrate the multiple webapps and slots using powershell. Where enabling vnet integration for webapps is working fine, but in the same way for webapp slots its not working.

```
$RGName = "web app resource group name "
$vnetName = "yashvnet01"
$VnetRG = "vnet name"
$subnetName = "subnet name"

$Vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetName -ResourceGroupName $VnetRG
$subnet = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $subnetName -VirtualNetwork $Vnet

$Vnet.Id

##Add vnet integration to the webapps in the specific Resource group
$Webapps=Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $RGname
$Webapps.Name

ForEach($webapp in $Webapps.Name)
{
Write-Host "Adding Vnet intergation to the $webapp"

az webapp vnet-integration add --resource-group $RGname --name $webapp --vnet $Vnet.Id --subnet $subnetName

Write-Host "Successfully added Vnet intergation to the $webapp"
}
```

How can we do the same for multiple webapp slot.

I would be glad if someone helps me on this.

Cheers
Rewanth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below script to apply v-net intergration on the webapps slots.

```
Connect-AzAccount

$RGName = "yourresourcegroupname"
$vnetName = "vnetname"
$VnetRG = "vnet resource group name"
$subnetName = "subnetname"

$Vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetName -ResourceGroupName $VnetRG
$subnet = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $subnetName -VirtualNetwork $Vnet

$Vnet.Id

$Webapps=Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $RGname
$Webapps.Name

##Add vnet integration to the webapps slots in the specific Resource group

ForEach($webapp in $Webapps.Name)
{
#Webapp slot
$WebappsSlot = Get-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Name $webapp
$WebappsSlot.Name

ForEach($webappSlot in $WebappsSlot.Name) {

$s = $webappSlot -replace $webapp + "/"

Write-Host "Adding Vnet intergation to the $s"

az webapp vnet-integration add --resource-group $RGname --name $webapp --vnet $Vnet.Id --subnet $subnetName -s $s

Write-Host "Successfully added Vnet intergation to the $s"
}
}
```

**Output for test:**

[image]

**Note:**

Please make sure to use the updated az version while running the above code . The az cli version used for the above is `2.71.1` . You can upgrade az version using command `az upgrade` in powershell.

Comment: Awesome. It worked locally. 
Thank you so much. You are lifesaver.
Now i'm trying to do this through the azure devops azure cli release tasks.